# Flyway long migration with parallel process

Tags: parallel-processing, flyway

If I have long migration script with batch of changes, does it run inside transaction? I have suspicion that it is possible to change the current schema in the middle of migration by the parallel migration which uses same dataSource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each Flyway instance uses its own connection and each migration is run within a transaction.